# Looping variable to writing sum in one file in R

Tags: r

I want use R to write two values and their sum into a single file. Is there any way to make this a real loop?

```
write(c('P_1', 'P_1', sum(V[P_1, P_1])), file = 'P.tab', append = T, ncolumns = 3)
write(c('P_1', 'P_2', sum(V[P_1, P_2])), file = 'P.tab', append = T, ncolumns = 3)
write(c('P_1', 'P_3', sum(V[P_1, P_3])), file = 'P.tab', append = T, ncolumns = 3) 
write(c('P_1', 'P_4', sum(V[P_1, P_4])), file = 'P.tab', append = T, ncolumns = 3)
write(c('P_1', 'P_5', sum(V[P_1, P_5])), file = 'P.tab', append = T, ncolumns = 3)
.
.
.
```

Comment: You should create a data.frame first, with all the values, and then saving using `write.table`.  you can start with this `expand.grid(paste0('P_',1:4),paste0('P_',1:4))`